# How to calculate resistance to output a specific volt and and amp from a transistor collector terminal?

Tags: led, resistors, bjt

Hello Everyone .As I am a very newbie to electronics, I need to calculate the suitable resistance for connecting an LED to the collector pin of the BJT.

Here is my diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMcfxz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Components:

1. 2N2222 BJT.
2. 100R ohm.
3. 5v , 500mA DC power supply.

Connection Explanation:

1. Connected transistor emitter to 5v source negative terminal.
2. Connected transistor base to the positive terminal through 100R ohm.

The collector outputs 5v and very near to 2Amp output, now I need to connect an LED of 3 volt and 20mA to the collector terminal, so I need to calculate the resistance which I don't know how to.

Can anyone tell me how to calculate the resistance at output 5v 2A to convert into LED's required volt and amps?

Sorry in advance for bad diagram sketch

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Fix your schematic and use the correct symbols for a BJT. There is a schematic editor built into each question and answer.

Comment: -1 for extremely sloppy drawing. Go search this site for questions about switching LEDs on and off using a transistor. Pay attention to how the schematics are drawn, then draw yours in a similar way.

Comment: I have drawn the schematic, sorry for the previous mistake

Comment: There have been questions here before, on the correct resistor for driving a LED. I would recommend searching for some of them.

Comment: Please @Drummond can u provide me the link

Comment: You'll want two resistors so that the LED current is independent of the transistor gain.  Practically speaking, figure out the LED current limit resistor as if the transistor were not there.   Then use a base resistor maybe 20 times larger than that.  Of course having the transistor at all only makes sense if you are trying to control the LED from something with limited current drive such as an MCU output pin; otherwise you could just use the supply, LED, and LED current limit resistor.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I am actually making a dark sensor circuit so need to calculate the suitable resistor for the led so that the current of the collector pin won't damage it.

Comment: Properly controlling the LED current is *exactly* what my comment above addressed.  Surely you can find some guidance on calculating LED current from a voltage-mode power supply on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you could use the transistor's current gain to calculate the required Base resistor value. However this is a poor method of determining Collector current because (due to [process variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_variation_(semiconductor))) the current gain may vary widely between individual parts, as well as with temperature and (to a lesser extent at medium values) Collector current and voltage.

Looking at the [2N2222 datasheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20070927213500if_/http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/PN/PN2222.pdf) we see that at 150mA the DC current gain at 25 °C could be anywhere from 100 to 300 depending on the particular unit. If we assume a value in the middle of this range (200) then for a Collector current of 20 mA the Base current needs to be 20 mA / 200 = 100 μA. Assuming the Base-Emitter junction drops 0.7 V at this current, the resistor has 5 V - 0.7 V = 4.3 V across it. [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) then says the resistance must be 4.3 V / 100 μA = 43 kΩ.

However if your individual transistor is at the low or high end of the h<sub>FE</sub> range then the LED current could be as low as 10 mA (100 μA * 100) or as high as 30 mA (100 μA * 300). If your LED is rated for 20 mA maximum then you will have to calculate using the *maximum* transistor gain of 300 giving a resistance value of 64.5 kΩ, and then the LED current at minimum gain would only be 6.7 mA. With the lower gain transistor the LED would still light, but less brightly.

Current gain also increases as temperature increases, which can cause [thermal runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway) if the transistor gets too hot. This probably won't happen in your circuit due to the low transistor heating at 30 mA, but could be a problem at higher current and/or voltage. Below is a graph of *typical* h<sub>FE</sub> vs. Collector current for a [2N2222A](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N2222A-D.PDF) at different temperatures. You can see a wide variation even for this typical example. For a unit at the extremes of the range it could be even higher or lower.

[image]

There are 3 simple ways to improve the accuracy of setting Collector current.

1. Measure the individual transistor's current gain, and choose a resistor value to suit. The manufacturer may measure gain at the factory and then put a letter after the part number to indicate the 'bin' (range of values) the transistor belong in, so you can purchase parts with more accurately defined specs.
2. Put a variable resistor or [trimpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmer_(electronics)#Resistors) in series with the Base resistor, then adjust it to get the resistance required for a *measured* Collector current of 20 mA.
3. Add a resistor in series with the LED to limit maximum Collector current. With this method you choose the Base resistance required to get *at least* 20 mA at minimum h<sub>FE</sub>, then calculate the *Collector* resistance required to not exceed 20 mA.

Putting a current limiting resistor in the Collector circuit and providing 'excess' Base current makes the transistor act as a switch, turning fully on when the control voltage is applied no matter what the individual transistor's current gain may be, while the Collector resistor sets the load current. This is the preferred method for your circuit because it makes LED brightness insensitive to transistor current gain.

Say you have an LED which drops 3 V at 20 mA. This leaves 5 V - 3 V = 2 V after the LED. With the correct LED resistor value, If the transistor attempts to draw more than 20 mA then its Collector voltage will drop to the saturation voltage, which for the 2N2222 is ~0.1 V at 20 mA. Therefore the LED resistance required is ~(2 V - 0.1 V) / 20 mA = ~95 Ω. The Base resistance required is 4.3 V / (20 mA / 100) = ~22 kΩ. To ensure 'excess' Base current you could use an even lower value, eg. 10 kΩ.

Comment: Very clearly explained, thanks ..